# Download image and display it

Tags: android

The main purpose of app is to download and display image, but when I try to launch app it crashes.

Here is my code.

```
private DownloadImageTask task;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    task = new DownloadImageTask();
    task.onPostExecute(task.doInBackground("http://parkcinema.az/uploads/structures/movies/images/xickok_poster1_resized.jpg"));
    }

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}        

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      img.setImageBitmap(result);           
}
}
```

Here is LogCat:

```
02-24 11:04:56.814: E/Trace(957): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-24 11:04:57.384: D/AndroidRuntime(957): Shutting down VM
02-24 11:04:57.384: W/dalvikvm(957): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bakumovies/com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:49)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-24 11:04:57.404: E/AndroidRuntime(957):  ... 11 more
```

And here is .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="144dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't understand why it crashes. Image downloading is launched in new thread, imageview object is created. I am completely confused with this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually **read** the error? It says: `NullPointerException: println needs a message`, which seems to be a problem with your `Log.e`-statement. See the [Bug-Report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9211)

Comment: @Math Daimon try my solution and let me know any problem if you will have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for NPE (Null Pointer Exception)

> Log.e("Error", e.getMessage()); //e.getMessage() is NULL so its giving NPE.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  task = new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://parkcinema.az/uploads/structures/movies/images/xickok_poster1_resized.jpg");
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(urldisplay).openConnection().getInputStream());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}
```

> ADD this permission in AndroidManifest.xml because you are doing internet operation.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have commented out this line of code, tried to launch the app. It didn't crash, but image didn't appear :/

Comment: urldisplay is string, you're trying to invocate openConnection() method on string.

Comment: @Math Daimon now check it.

Comment: @MathDaimon I have checked the logcat please add the permission as i told above and accept its its solve your problem.

Comment: This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it will help but you don't (possibly shouldn't) call doInBackground AsyncTask method manually. Android will do this itself. In fact the whole logic of your AsyncTask is a little off. onPostExecute is called when doInBackground has finished.

Comment: In fact, try changing task.onPostexecute(...) to task.execute(...), passing just your url string. That should help! :)

Comment: I have tried this, didn't help :(
task.execute("http://parkcinema.az/uploads/structures/movies/images/xickok_poster1_resized.jpg");